# How to make the static member type of a class point to the type of the subclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

```
class SingletonBaseClass {
  static singleton: SingletonBaseClass | null = null;

  static instance() {
    if (!this.singleton) {
      this.singleton = new this();
    }
    return this.singleton;
  }

  static destroy() {
    this.singleton = null;
  }
}

class Demo extends SingletonBaseClass {
  hello() { }
}

Demo.instance().hello();
```

Above is the code, `Demo.instance()` will be considered an instance of `SingletonBaseClass` instead of `Demo`, so `Demo.instance().hello()` will report a TypeScript error.

Is there any way to make the return type of `Demo.instance()` be `SingletonBaseClass`?

Comment: `this` in a static member refers to the type of the  class. That said, using the class Singleton pattern in JavaScript or TypeScript code is one of the worst practices possible

Answer (score 0):

you could just cast it:

```
(Demo.instance() as Demo).hello();
```